# GlassFish port changed, but app still running on old one

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

I changed the GlassFish Server 4.1 port from 8084 to 8090 in *domain.xml*. After that, I removed and added GlassFish server again in Netbeans. In GlassFish Server properties HTTP port is now 8090 as it should be, but when I deploy and run application, it runs on:

```
http://localhost:8084/myapp/
```

I have WebService in my Java Web application which I can't test (right click on web service -> Test Web Service). I get this error:

```
Unable to open web service tester page:
http://localhost:8084/myapp/myWebService
Make sure the service has been deployed succesfully, and the server is running
```

Being unable to start GlassFish Server (Error: Could not start GlassFish Server: HTTP or HTTPS listener port is occupied while server is not running) is the reason I have changed the server port in domain.xml.

So, what is the reason my app is still running on port 8084 instead of new port 8090?

Is that the reason wsdl file is not created in my application, after creating Web Service?

Edit:
[Command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTMOd.png)

[Command prompt - find process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sECdH.png)

Comment: if you changed it in the `domain.xml`, you have probably changed the value for the `default-config`, which is just a template and not used by GlassFish. Make sure you change the property in the `server-config` section. (Alternatively, change the property in both places to make sure it's the right place).

Comment: Under server-config -> http-listener-1, port was already 8090 as it should be, port in default-config -> http-listener-1 was something like #{xxx} (I guess it is reference to server-config) and I changed it to 8090, removed GlassFish server from Netbeans Servers and added it again, but same thing as before...Have any other idea?

Comment: Did you actually restart GlassFish? Or just remove it and re-add it in NetBeans?

Comment: Yes, restarted it. I found this in GlassFish Server output log after re-adding and restarting server:

`Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8090`
`Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181`
`Info:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848`

Comment: based on the screenshot you uploaded, it seems like the old GlassFish is still running. Maybe try to terminate both processes and start GlassFish again. It could be that your second attempt to start GlassFish failed?

Comment: I edited my question and added Command-Prompt screenshot, both ports seem to be occupied

Comment: Added one more screenshot to my question. Port 8084 is used by process with ID 3580, which is java.exe [Java(TM) Platform SE binary]. Should I kill it forcefully?

Comment: Ok, after killing process on port 8084 my app was still running on that port insted of 8090, but then I changed Glassfish port to 8084 again and it seems to be working. So, I guess problem is solved, Thanks for your help